# UserControl with List<T> property - any chance for declarative definition?

Tags: wpf, xaml, generics, generic-list

I have a UserControl with the following Property:

```
public List<Rect> HotSpots
{
   get { return (List<Rect>)GetValue(HotSpotsProperty); }
   set { SetValue(HotSpotsProperty, value); }
}

public static readonly DependencyProperty HotSpotsProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("HotSpots", typeof(List<Rect>), typeof(ImageViewPort), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(HotSpotsChanged));
```

Since compiled XAML (XAML 2006 by default) doesn't support generics the way the 2009 specification allows, I wonder is there any chance of doing something like the following:

```
<WPF:ImageViewPort Grid.Row="1">
   <WPF:ImageViewPort.HotSpots>
      <Rect Location="0,0" Height="30" Width="50"></Rect>
       <Rect Location="10,35" Height="30" Width="20"></Rect>
   </WPF:ImageViewPort.HotSpots>
 </WPF:ImageViewPort>
```

Or is my only chance a Binding like the following?

```
<WPF:ImageViewPort Grid.Row="1" HotSpots="{Binding Path=HotSpots}"/>
```

Just out of curiosity, the limitation seems to be XAML's support for generics, so writing a List derivate should do the trick, shouldn't it?

Comment: public class Rectlist : List<Rect> //should work in your binding

Comment: The Binding works fine, like you said.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since XAML isn't used to **add to** Collections but rather to **setting** them, I've had to create a wrapping XAML Node that initializes the Collection. Since the Collection is generic, I can't do this as it is, but have to create a wrapper like so :

```
public class HotSpotList : List<Rect> {}
```

In my XAML then, I can set it like so:

```
<WPF:ImageViewPort.HotSpots>
  <HotSpotList>
   <Rect Location="0,0" Height="30" Width="50"></Rect>
   <Rect Location="10,35" Height="30" Width="20"></Rect>
  </HotSpotList>
</WPF:ImageViewPort.HotSpots>
```

Easy enough, once you've seen it work =)

Answer (score 1):

The XAML code you posted should work fine, you just need to make sure the `HotSpots` collection is initialized beforehand. Just initialize it in the constructor of your `ImageViewPort` class

Comment: Hi Thomas, actually the code doesn't throw any exceptions, but when the setter of the HotSpots Property is reached, the collection that is passed in has no elements. That, of course, with the collection initialized in the ctor.

Comment: The setter is not supposed to be reached (except when you initialize the property in the ctor); the Rects should be added to the existing collection

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to further specify what happens: I set a breakpoint in HotSpotsChanged, which fires when the DP is changed. Oddly enough, the code in there is only executed once (on constructor call), but not when the XAML is resolved...

Comment: @SebastianEdelmeier, that's how it's supposed to work... the list is only initialized once. When the HotSpots defined in XAML are parsed, it doesn't assign a new collection to the property, it adds them to the current one. But since it is a `List<T>`, you're not getting a notification when it happens... you should try to use an `ObservableCollection<T>` instead

Comment: that makes perfect sense to me, but it doesn't work. I think I should probably check the ValueCoerced Callback...